# PHP error in .xml file?

Tags: php, xml, .htaccess

OK firstly, I added this line to my .htaccess file so the php engine parses php code in .xml file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .phtml .html .xml
```

After that when I view an .xml file I get this PHP error:

**Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/test.xml on line 1**

But line 1 is not even php infact this is line 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because `<?` is the short opening tag for php.

Try `<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'; ?>`

Comment: I've had problems with even this solution - you may need to do `<?php echo '<' . '?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?' . '>'; ?>`

Comment: What pix0r said.  The problem with Apikot's answer is the '?>' sequence appearing in the string, whereas in PHP the characters '?>' should never appear even in a string.

Comment: ... interestingly, PHP's own parser tolerates it.  The reason I avoid it is that syntax highlighting text editors or IDEs often don't.

Comment: Out of my experience, php doesn't have any problems with '?>' in a string. Care to elaborate please?

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, sad but true, it's the doctype being seen as the PHP opening short tag.  You have a few options:

1. Take XML out of the list of files for PHP to parse in the .htaccess file
2. Wrap all of your xml declarations in PHP:

   `<?php print('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'); ?>`
3. Turn off `short_open_tag` in .htaccess or the php.ini.  This means that PHP will only accept **`<?php`** as an opening tag and will ignore **`<?`**.

Comment: If you want the XML file to remain well-formed XML even with the PHP inside it, hide the closing ‘?>’. eg. print('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?'.'>');

Comment: Would this really let it remain a valid XML document on the server side?  I don't think having a PHP open tag as the first viable character would do the job.  I think if you take this approach you can't make it a valid XML document on the server... only on output.

Comment: Yes, a PHP open tag in the long form makes an XML Processing Instruction. It's quite valid to have a PI (or Comment) outside the root documentElement.

Comment: (The main problem encountered when trying to make PHP files also well-formed XML is coming up with alternatives for inserting content into attribute values and optionally-including attributes, since you can't put a PI inside an element or attribute.)

Answer (score 4):

Alternative 4, in addition to daniel's: drop the <?xml...?> declaration completely.

Since ‘1.0’ and ‘utf-8’ are the defaults for XML, it's completely redundant; including the XML declaration here gains you nothing.