# How can I get PHP to stop trying to parse my XML?

Tags: php, xml

I'm working on a school project where we have to encode literary texts into XML, and then post them on our web pages. I have a web page that mostly uses HTML and CSS, but occasionally uses a PHP include in order to get all my headers and footers modular and in separate files. The problem with this setup is, when I have a php include to include (i.e. import) my XML file, I get this parsing error: `Parse error: parse error in /home1/j/jpr226/public_html/homestead.xml on line 1`, where line 1 is just the xml declaration, something like `<?xml version="1.0"?>`.

If I copy-and-paste the XML file into the HTML file, it seems to work roughly as expected, but when I use php to include this file, I get this error.

I'm guessing PHP is trying to parse this XML file somehow, and when it can't do that, it generates this error. Is there a way to tell PHP to lay off, and stop trying to interpret my XML file?

This is from http://i5.nyu.edu/~jpr226/texts.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP error in .xml file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706329/php-error-in-xml-file)

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't `include()` anything that's not php.  Read the file with `file_get_contents()` instead.
2. Disable the `short_open_tag` ini directive.  When short_open_tag is on, `<?` is equivalent to `<?php`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try HTML-encoding the XML?

```
$myXMLCode = htmlspecialchars($myXMLCode);
echo $myXMLCode;
```

Edit: It sounds like the PHP preprocessor is reading `<?` as a starting PHP tag. Did you disable  short tags?

```
ini_set("short_open_tag", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn off short open tag in PHP.ini.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php